# (SOLVED) getUid can only be called from within the same library group (groupId=com.google.firebase)

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to save a user in the repository with a method, when I **set the document id** as **the current user id logged in** it gives me this error

> user.getUid can only be called from within the same library group (groupId=com.google.firebase)

```
class FirebaseRepository {
    var db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    var auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

    var user = auth.currentUser

    fun saveUser(user: User): Task<Void>{
        var documentReference = db.collection("users").document(user.uid).set(user)
    }
}
```

But when I do set the variable `var user = auth.currentUser` inside the method works.

Question: What's going on there? What am I missing?

Solution: I didn't notice there were 2 user variables (Class variable and method variable), I was using the method variable instead the auth variable.

Comment: Have you tried to use `return db.collection("users").document(user.uid).set(user)`?

Comment: Ok, it was my fault there are 2 users (Class variable and method variable), and I didn't notice I was using the method one, totally my bad!

Comment: If you have a solution to your own question, you can post it as an answer and accept it as correct instead of editing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:** I didn't notice there were 2 user variables (Class variable and method variable), I was using the method variable instead the auth variable.

Comment: ```testing
multiple```